# Python: How to appending type dictionary with same key

Tags: python, dictionary

> i have problem with appending dictionary , this situation when the key
>   dictionary same , this is the code

```
import random
temp_data = {}

def data_value():
    data = []
    for x in range (1,6):
        val = random.randrange(0, 101, 2)
        data.append(val)
    return data

for x in range(1,11):
    if x == 3:
        temp_data.update({ "name" : "Cat" , "total" : data_value() })
    if x == 4:
        temp_data.update({ "name" : "Dog" , "total" : data_value()})
    if x == 5:
        temp_data.update({ "name" : "Chicken" , "total" : data_value()})        
print temp_data
```

ouput will be

```
{'total': [20, 84, 10, 14, 10], 'name': 'Chicken'}
```

i want make output like

```
{'total': [20, 84, 10, 14, 10], 'name': 'Cat'},
{'total': [20, 84, 10, 14, 10], 'name': 'Dog'},
{'total': [20, 84, 10, 14, 10], 'name': 'Chicken'}
```

hem, i have tried with append but it can't because the data must be array list.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must put the dictionary into array list , and append with it.

```
import random
temp_data = {}
temp_list = []
def data_value():
    data = []
    for x in range (1,6):
        val = random.randrange(0, 101, 2)
        data.append(val)
    return data

for x in range(1,11):
    if x == 3:
        temp_data = { "name" : "Cat" , "total" : data_value()}  
        temp_list.append(temp_data)
    if x == 4:
        temp_data = { "name" : "Dog" , "total" : data_value()}
        temp_list.append(temp_data)     
    if x == 5:
        temp_data = { "name" : "Chicken" , "total" : data_value()}
        temp_list.append(temp_data)
print temp_list
```

output will be :

```
[
 {'total': [88, 26, 8, 28, 54], 'name': 'Cat'},
 {'total': [16, 68, 94, 20, 16], 'name': 'Dog'},
 {'total': [88, 92, 56, 62, 46], 'name': 'Chicken'}
]
```

^^ CMIIW but the output still be array list

and some i have some trick convert array list into string and replace the tag [{ and }]
like this

```
result_data =  str(temp_list)
temp_rest = result_data.replace("[{", "{")
temp_rest = temp_rest.replace("}]", "}")
print temp_rest
```

Final Output like this

```
 {'total': [88, 26, 8, 28, 54], 'name': 'Cat'},
 {'total': [16, 68, 94, 20, 16], 'name': 'Dog'},
 {'total': [88, 92, 56, 62, 46], 'name': 'Chicken'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  a list:

```
temp_data = [] # Its a list now
for x in range(1,11):
    if x == 3:
        temp_data.append({ "name" : "Cat" , "total" : data_value() }) # Use list.append()
    if x == 4:
        temp_data.append({ "name" : "Dog" , "total" : data_value()})
    if x == 5:
        temp_data.append({ "name" : "Chicken" , "total" : data_value()})        
print temp_data
```